# Mysteriously Undefined Function

Tags: javascript

I've been looking at this for a long time now, and had several other people look over it. None of whom can spot what's causing this issue.

Something is causing the function validate() to be undefined by the time it gets to the body of the page. I belive there must be some error earlier in the program that is causing the browser to stop processing javascript before then, but I can't find it.

Full JS content:
http://pastebin.com/9b0pwktA

Any insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I would use a debugger before asking people to execute that much JavaScript in their brains. The tools will do a much better job of it.

Comment: Put the `script` after the body or wrap it in an `onload` function

Comment: The only errors I've been able to get out of one have been what I saided... that the function is undefined. And I for the life of my can't discern WHY. If you can recommend a good debugger, I'd be more than happy to continue my own quest.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Browsers have built-in debuggers!

Comment: Those regular expressions are all wrong, by the way.  They should not be in quotes.

Comment: I'm especially intrigued by the `return false; return dataIsGood;` line...I can guarrantee that second statement will never be executed. Just as a side note, JavaScript is "truthy, falsy" meaning you don't have to check `if(errorText.length > 0)` or `input[i].length == "0"`. In JavaScript 0, null, undefined and false all evaluate to false. A simple `if(errorText.length)` will do.

Comment: Please include the *relevant* part your code in the question.

Comment: Warlock, the return false line was a debugging tool to try and determine why it was submitting invalid data, and prevent it from advancing to the next page(and clearing my console). Sorry, should have cleared that before I put it here, but I forgot it was there.

Comment: Felix, I... I want to. But I don't know what's causing the browser to fail so sompletely, and thus don't know what can safely be omitted without hiding the error.

Comment: @AlexaDeWit: You can start by removing bits of your code and see if the error is still occurring. If yes, continue. If not, the piece you just removed is responsible for the error.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, just open the developer console before running your code and it will show you exactly where things are breaking.

Comment: @FelixKling in this case, that wouldn't help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed that code (at least visibility of validate method), by removing:

```
language="text/javascript"
```

from

```
<script language="text/javascript">
```

to make:

```
<script>
```

Try that out!

*Edit...*
There are numerous other bugs, but I targeted the specific problem the question was asking about.

Comment: Great catch!! That's probably the problem, though it won't work anyway. OP, all you need is `<script>` unless you want the code to *not* be evaluated as JavaScript.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `type="text/javascript"` and `language="javascript"` are considered valid, but you can't mix the two.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks :)  There are problems throughout the rest of the code, like Postal label's for attribute associated with a non-postal input field... etc etc etc... but I solved the OP's question.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something that painfully trivial. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TomPace Yeah, thanks Tom a tonne. I know it still has other errors, I just didn't see them because the program wasn't advancing far enough to debuf them. I really appreciate that catch.

Comment: Nicely done +1. It's probably worth mentioning too that `width=400px` is invalid CSS. It should be `width: 400px;`